# Open Word from Excel colors wrong

Tags: vba, excel

Using VBA code in Excel I create a new Word document in which I insert some other documents I already have on disk.

Everything works fine, except for the fact that some background shading colors I have in my documents are different.

Relevant snipets of code follow:

```
   Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wdApp Is Nothing Then
        Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        bNewApp = True
    End If
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add
    wdDoc.PageSetup.PaperSize = wdA4
    wdApp.Visible = True
[...]
wdDoc.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Range.InsertFile Filename:=curpath & "\" & sh.Cells(r, 7).Value
```

As you can see, there's nothing there to change the color, I believe it (maybe?) has to do with some default parameters used when opening a Word document.

Any suggestions on how to fix this situation?

EDIT:
here are 2 screenshots: the original document and the document opened by VBA:
[image: this is how it's supposed to look]

[image: and this is the orange 2 shades lighter]

Comment: can you add a screenshot of the document before and after showing the differences

Comment: What happens if you cut VBA out of the loop and do this manually? The only thing I can think of is that the document you are trying to insert uses custom colors which aren't saved with the document but instead reside in the instance of word of which generated it (maybe in some registry entry?). Google gives a lot of hits involving "saving custom colors in word" which suggests that it is a known problem.

Comment: You are on to something! If I copy / paste by hand, the colors are messed up. They are preserved only if I use the "Keep formatting" option.